# list named pipes on different computer

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

There are plenty of examples of how to list pipes on the same computer (using pipelist utility, or call to ntddl/NtQueryDirectoryFile). However, I need to list pipes on a remote system (at the same domain or workgroup).
Attempt to access "\\<ipaddr>\Pipe" programmatically returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError - 123.

```
hPipe = CreateFile(L"\\\\10.0.0.11\\Pipe\\", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();  // returns 123
if(hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 1;
```

Any insight is appreciated...

Comment: Easiest solution would be to run the code on the target machine. [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) does that. The author also published an article, where he [describes how PsExec works](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec).

Comment: Thank you for the idea! PsExec would probably work. And looks like it is possible to do similar stuff programmatically. However, I wanted to go further - write application to read from named pipe on a different computer. I found some suggestions to use LogonUser/Impersonate api, and also information about named pipes filtering. The latter specifies to which pipes connection is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that named pipes can work across network provided correct security context. For example, if the same domain user logged on two workstations, named pipes are working.

Unfortunately, I had not been able to find a way to list pipes on different computer. C# Directory.GetFiles(@"\host\Pipe") throws exception "Incorrect function".

So, my answer: there is no way to obtain list of named pipes on different computer in Win32. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I decided to implement socket server that will provide list of open pipes via TCP.

Edit: Later I found source for PAExec utility on github. From the source I learned how to use WNetOpenEnum/WNetAddConnection2 to connect to remote\IPC$ and inject my own utility that returns list of open pipes.